# While resolving dependency: node-clean-css encountered following error

Tags: dependencies

While resolving "dependency not satisfiable:node-clean-css" I was executing following set of commands:

1. sudo apt-get install nodejs
2. sudo apt-get install npm
3. sudo npm install -g less
4. sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
5. sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/lessc /usr/bin/lessc
6. sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

First two commands executed successfully. While I executed third command, I encountered following error As shown in screenshot [image: npm error]